# How to position rectangle in ColumnLayout

Tags: python, qt, qml, qtquick2, pyqt5

I have the following (simplified) QML code:

```
ColumnLayout {
    spacing: 1

    Repeater {
        model: 2

        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            height: childrenRect.height
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            Text {
                text: "test"
                color: "black"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected it to render 2 `Text` elements one under another, both filling the column width, but instead, the width is set to something close to 0. Setting `Layout.minimumWidth: childrenRect.width` kind of helps, but the values are not stretched if the text has different length.

When instead of the repeater I just copy & paste the rectangle part multiple times, all works as expected.

To me, that looks like a bug, but maybe I'm missing something. Can anyone shed some light on that?

The result I'm trying to achieve is to have a list of components with various background color.

Comment: try to give the rectangle (in the repeater) a width, cause in your example it will not be drawn and the repeater will not work

Comment: I cannot see differences in using the `Repeater` or not. Setting an explicit `width` to the `ColumnLayout` solves the issue with the `width` of the  `Rectangle`. Is it the example too minimal?

Comment: not setting the width there is actually on purpose. That's why `Layout.fillWidth: true` is there. The width stretch to fill the column

Comment: I don't the difference between your code or using two `Rectangles`. Do you have an example (image or something) to see what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Chris if you don't want to set the `width` set `anchors.fill: parent` (or other anchors) and it would work...you still need some information to size the layout or it would not be possible to fill the space (which space?). It sounds like you want a `Column` not a `ColumnLayout`.

Comment: It's not possible to set anchors.fill in a ColumnLayout (reports an error). What I want is an column of elements with the same width (width of the widest). Requirement is simple enough, not sure why this is such a headache :/